# PHP saving a document with an ObjectId is being converted to Object->oid

Tags: php, mongodb, objectid

I am saving some documents with `$ownership->_id = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($ownership->_id);` but besides it saving as `ObjectId` in the database, it is saving as an `Object` with `"oid" : "60f98b137af3950d2a7e6c86"`.

It is preventing me from doing a `$lookup` because it is not an `ObjectId` for the document in another collection.

Anyone have been on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Someone put the code in our MongoDB wrapper to cast objects to arrays. So, the `MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId` was being converted to an array with a string element with key `oid`.